# Data Structure, independent of volume of data in it

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

Is there any data structure in which locating a data is independent of its volume ?

Comment: In what language, context, etc?

Comment: i just mean in the field of data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"locating a data is independent of volume of data in it" - I assume this means O(1) for get operations.  That would be a hash map.

This presumes that you fetch the object based on the hash.

If you have to check each element to see if an attribute matches a particular value, like your `rson` or `ern` or any other parts of it, then you have to make that value the key up front.

If you have several values that you need to search on - all of the must be unique and immutable - you can create several maps, one for each value.  That lets you search on more than one.  But they have to all be unique, immutable, and known up front.

If you don't establish the key up front it's O(N), which means you have to check every element in turn until you find what you want.  On average, this time will increase as the size of the collection grows.  That's what O(N) means.

Comment: Does it remain similar(not exactly same but not too high as well) while seeking data using parts of it ? I mean locating `person` using `rson` as a clue.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: i mean time for locating `person` when one has `rson` or `ern`or any other parts of it. Can hash table be used for these situations ? Sorry for my poor explanation, i don't belong to this field but m curious :)

Comment: Thanx that explains pretty much, but still is there better alternatives?

Comment: lol, thanx for your time...no offense but m not here for quality profile

Comment: I'm not here to bother answering your questions.  Good luck in the future.